# How to use ndk file_descriptor_jni.h?

Tags: c, android-ndk, java-native-interface, file-descriptor

I want to create a Java FileDescriptor object on C!

There are too few related instructions.

It has been tried for a long time and cannot be called successfully.

```
AFileDescriptor_create(JNIEnv *env)

AFileDescriptor_getFd(JNIEnv *env, jobject fileDescriptor)

AFileDescriptor_setFd(JNIEnv *env, jobject fileDescriptor, int fd)
```

https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/file-descriptor

Comment: ***cannot be called successfully*** Why? Do you face any issues? Please elaborate.

Comment: @Qiuyan did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @garrilla https://github.com/iamverycute/ASerialPort